# Ranking / Case Statement referencing a CTE Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following case expression that I need help revising - I am not sure how to properly format this case statement:

```
,case when Ranking(statusing_Facility_CD) <> Ranking-1(Statusing_Facility_CD) 
 and Ranking(Equipment_Status_Type_CD)='ENR' and Ranking-1(Equipment_Status_Type_CD)='ARV' 
 then DATEDIFF(hh,Ranking(Status_Time,Ranking-1(Status_Time) end as ENR_TO_ARV
```

The Result I am going for is to have another column named 'ENR_ARV_Time' that would return the datediff(hh) for the Statusing_Facility_CD where the equipment_Status_type_cd = 'ENR':

```
Equipment_Unit_NB|Statusing_Facility_CD| Status_Time      | Equipment_Status_Type_CD| Ranking 
117349                  402             2020-12-23 10:37:26          ARR     1      
117349                  422             2020-12-23 05:07:17          ENR     2      
117349                  422             2020-12-22 22:45:05          LDD     3      
117349                  422             2020-12-21 20:22:05          LDG     4      
117349                  422             2020-12-21 14:22:37          UAD     5      
117349                  422             2020-12-21 08:25:44          ARV     6      
117349                  621             2020-12-21 02:03:45          ENR     7      
117349                  621             2020-12-20 17:18:44          ARR     8      
117349                  347             2020-12-20 04:51:25          ENR     9      
117349                  347             2020-12-20 03:37:45          LDD    10
```

Comment: That is a `CASE` **expression**, it returns a scalar value; T-SQL doesn't `Case` (`Switch`) statements, which control the operational flow of a process.

Comment: It doesn't look like we need all of this code to help you here, we just need to bare minimum to both replicate your problem and be able to run; what is known as a [mre]. IN your query, you have litered it with `NOLOCK` hints; you do understand what they do and the impact on the reliability of your results it has, correct? The fact you've used it so much suggests not. Also, you have a `GROUP BY in your query, but there aren't any aggregate functions; that seems wrong too. Why are you grouping if you're not aggregating?

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: `[dbo].[MFD].[EQP_EQP_SPOT_DTL]` You have a DATABASE named dbo? Yikes! Are you stuck with this schema?

Comment: @SMor Removed actual database names

Comment: @larnu I have more script above this cte that I did not include in this post which needs the group by..

Comment: Your aliasing doesn't make much sense either, I'm afraid. "a" is for "equipment", "b" is for "facility"? `equipment` doesn't even *have* an `a` in it, so why is that it's alias? Use aliases that make sense. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: *"Removed actual database names "* You've missed the point of @SMor 's comment if you remove them from your question; the problem isn't that they are there, it's that you have a database named `dbo`. Considering that the default schema for a database is also `dbo` that is really confusing.

Comment: @larnu thank for the instructions - would you be able to help with the case statement?

Comment: *"I have more script above this cte"* But that isn't inside the subquery with the `GROUP BY`. Show us actual meaningful, representative, and minimal code to show us the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: *"case statement?"* As [i mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65902432/ranking-case-statement-referencing-a-cte-table#comment116520385_65902432), T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements. But like I said, what you are after is unclear. Make a [mre].

Comment: AFAIK `Ranking(statusing_Facility_CD)` is not valid tsql nor is `Ranking-1(Statusing_Facility_CD)`. Yet you do not mention anything obvious about syntax errors. Is the first problem to overcome just how to calculate a rank (ignoring how you intend to use those values)?

Comment: @SMor I have the ranking complete - I just do not know how to format the case so that I can reference the rank for the statusing facility_CD and referencing the rank for the Equipment_Status_Type_CD. I want the case expression to look at for when the Statusing_facility_CDs do not match and if ranking='ENR' and Ranking-1='ARV' then do that datediff(hh) of those two timestamps. (notice rank 1 & rank 2) those two statusing facility codes do not match and where ranking=2, that equal 'ENR' and where Ranking =1 that equals 'ARV' so I want that datediff of rank 1 and rank 2.